# Pointer required for codility test problem

Tags: java, arrays

Below mentioned piece of code has a bug which needs to be eliminated by changing only 2 lines of code. The method solution returns true if value which is denoted by K is found in the Array passed to the method. It returns correct result for following input - 
    int A[]= {1,1,2,3,3};
    int K =3;
but provides wrong answer for following input- int A[] = {1,1,456,555, 987, 10000 }; 
                                        int K =555;
array should be non desc order.

i am not able to find bug in belowcode statement. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
public static bool solution(int[] A, int K){

    int n = A.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++){
        if (A[i] + 1 < A[i + 1])
            return false;
    }
    if (A[0] == 1 && A[n - 1] != K)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: Why "by changing only 2 lines of code"?

Comment: Sorry, I do not think that this question belongs to SO. I  think, the absurdest possible way to accomplish a simple task should(and can) never serve as a example for others to be adapted .

Comment: one solution is: for(int a:A){   if( a== K) return true; } return false;

Comment: The code as written appears to have nothing to do with the problem statement.

Comment: The answer to the above problem statement would be to remove the incorrect condition coded inside for loop and replace it with if(A[i] == K) return true ; Thanks !